# Multiple increments in Swift style for loops

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following loop in my Swift code:

```swift
for var i:Int = 0, j:Int = 0; i < rawDataOut.count; i += 4, ++j {
    maskPixels[j] = rawDataOut[i + 3]
}
```

I'm getting two warnings in Xcode:

1. C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift
2. '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3

I cannot see how to rewrite this in Swift's [For In Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) to take into account the two variables and the 4-stride without it getting messy. Is there a simple elegant translation?

Comment: `for i in 0..rawDataOut.count { let maskPixelIndex = i * 4 }`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Preconditions to answering this: looking over your example

I will assume that you intended to limit `i` by `i < rawDataOut.count-3` rather than `i < rawDataOut.count`, otherwise the `rawDataOut[i + 3]` element access by index wouldn't make much sense w.r.t. runtime safety. Anyway, without you showing us `rawDataOut`, this is an assumption we shall have to make.

Hence, your original loop (including a verifiable example) looks as follows

```
/* example data */
var rawDataOut = Array(1...40)
var maskPixels = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)

/* your pre-Swift 2.2/3.0 loop */
for var i: Int = 0, j: Int = 0; i < rawDataOut.count-3; i += 4, ++j {
    maskPixels[j] = rawDataOut[i + 3]
}

print(maskPixels) //[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]
```

---

### Using `for in ... where`

In your specific example case, the multiple increments have a simple relation (`j=4*i`) so we could solve this without even making use of an explicit `j` iterate, e.g.

```
/* example data */
var rawDataOut = Array(1...40)
var maskPixels = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)

/* your pre-Swift 2.2/3.0 loop */
for i in 0..<(rawDataOut.count-3) where i%4 == 0 {
    maskPixels[i/4] = rawDataOut[i + 3]
}

print(maskPixels) // [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]
```

but this is possibly not really of interest for the general discussion of two iterates. We move on to a 2-iterate method combining `stride` and `enumerate`.

---

### Combining `stride` and `enumerate`

One solution is to enumerate the `stride` described by iterate `i` in your loop above, and use the enumeration index to construct the second iterate (`j` above). In your example, the `enumerate` index exactly corresponds to `j`, i.e.

```
/* example data */
var rawDataOut = Array(1...40)
var maskPixels = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)

/* Swift >= 2.2 loop */
for (j, i) in 0.stride(to: rawDataOut.count-3, by: 4).enumerate() {
    maskPixels[j] = rawDataOut[i + 3]
}

print(maskPixels) // [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]
```

Note that in Swift 3 (as compared to 2.2), it seems as if the default implementations of `stride(to:by:)` and `stride(through:by:)` to protocol [`Strideable`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Strideable/) (as non-blueprinted extension methods) will be depracated, and that we're back to (as in Swift 1.2) using the global functions `stride(from:to:by:)` and `stride(from:through:by:)`, see e.g. the current master branch of [swift/stdlib/public/core/Stride.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Stride.swift)

---

### Trickier cases: resort to `while`

For trickier cases, say a signature in your pre-Swift 2.2 loop as

```
for var i: Int = 0, j: Int = 0; i < rawDataOut.count-3; i += 4, j += i { ... }
```

you're probably best of simply using a `while` loop with one iterate associated with the loop invariant, and a trailing iterate as a free variable; whether this is considered messy or not is a matter of taste, I suppose.

```
var i = 0, j = 0
while i < rawDataOut.count-3 {

    // ...

    // increase iterates
    i += 4
    j += i
}
```

I assume the reason for removing the C-style loop is that it's, in most cases, directly covered by `for in`, `stride` etc, and for cases where these don't suffice, a good old' `while`, most likely, will.

Comment: Great answer - really comprehensive, thanks. I do find the stride example confusing since in `for (j, i) in 0.stride(to: rawDataOut.count-3, by: 4).enumerate()` we're iterating a tuple `(j, i)` but only specifying one set of `to:` / `by:` constraints in `stride`. I'll read up on that.

Comment: @dumbledad happy to help! The stride itself doesn't generate a sequence of tuples (`0.stride(...)` just generates a sequence `0, 4, 8, ...`), but the `enumerate()` method (see [details for `SequenceType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/#func--enumerate)) generates a sequence of pairs `(idx,val)` where `idx` simply enimerates the, say, indices of the values `val` of the sequence onto which `.enumerate()` is applied. E.g. In the example above, `idx=0,1,2,...` for values `val=0,4,8,...`, specifically denoted `j` and `i` above, respectively.

Comment: (... hence, `enumerate()` is a good method of choice if one of your two indices simply runs from `0` and `++` as `0,1,2,...`)

Comment: it's cut-off a huge feature of for-loop, seem like they try to deprecate it

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4

```
for index in stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 2){
    print(index)
}
```